# Substitution with functional equations

Tags: functions, functional-equations

[image]

I've found this nice introduction worksheet that I started to work through with the goal to get a better understanding of functions and finding them in equations. I've gotten so far but in this one solution there is a few steps that is REALLY unclear. I'd appreciate if someone can check the edited screenshot and give me some pointers. Thank you!

Comment: $t=\frac{x-1}{x}\implies x=\frac{1}{1-t}$ you can re-arrange one into the other. Then you substitute back for $t$ and $x$ in the equations 1.1. to yield 1.2 equations. It was not helpful of the guy who wrote the solution to swap the order of the equations around between 1.1 to 1.2

Comment: No, these steps are REALLY clear. $t$ and $x$ is just a symbols; you can write, for example, $f(x+1)=f(x)$ ot $f(t+1)=f(t)$; both eqs. are the same

Comment: Direct substitution into which equation?  The equation in the problem statement.

Comment: It was really unclear until now! I've managed to solve it now. Thanks to everyone with their help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We begin with the expression

$$f(x)+f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=1+x \tag 1$$

The first substitution is to let $t=\frac{x-1}{x}\implies x=\frac{1}{1-t}$ from which $(1)$ becomes

$$f\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)+f\left(t\right)=1+\frac{1}{1-t} \tag2$$

Then, the development merely switches back from the dummy variable $t$ to $x$ to arrive at Equation $(1.1)$ from the posted question, namely

$$f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+f\left(x\right)=1+\frac{1}{1-x} \tag{1.1}$$

Next comes a second substitution in $(1)$.  Here, let $t=\frac{1}{1-x}\implies x=\frac{t-1}{t}$ so that $\frac{x-1}{x}=\frac{1}{-t}\frac{t}{t-1}=\frac{1}{1-t}$. Therefore, $(1)$ becomes

$$f\left(\frac{t-1}{t}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)=1+\frac{t-1}{t} \tag 3$$

Changing dummy variables in $(3)$ from $t$ to $x$ yields Equation $(1.2)$ from the posted question

$$f\left(\frac{t-1}{t}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)=1+\frac{t-1}{t} \tag{1.2}$$

If we enforce the second substitution $t=\frac{1}{1-x}\implies x=\frac{t-1}{t}$ into $(1.1)$, and switch dummy variables back, from $t$ to $x$, we obtain Equation $(1.3)$

$$f\left(x\right)+f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=1+x \tag{1.3}$$

The remaining part of the development uses $(1.1)-(1.3)$ to eliminate the terms with arguments $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{x-1}{x}$ to result in an expression for $f(x)$ alone.  In the posted question, this is done in two steps.  A more efficient way forward is to note simply that if we add the both sides of  $(1.1)$ and $(1.3)$, subtract from the result $(1.2)$, and finally divide by a factor of $2$, the resulting left-hand side if $f(x)$.

Comment: Some solution sheets can do with more like these =D. Thank you, clean and clear explanation of the original solution and contributing posts!

Comment: @user253171 Wow! Thank you so much!  I am still home and recovering from surgery 3 weeks ago.  Your comment really made my day!

Comment: Cool! May you have a speedy recovery ;)

Comment: Thanks!  It's been 27 days since surgery.